# ubuntu drivers stop working all of a sudden

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with windows 7. Today while i was working in ubuntu due to no power my laptop shutdown. later after getting the power i started the laptop again. now when i enter the ubuntu my

- external mouse not working
- wired lan is not showing
- wireless networking not showing
- display resolution shrinked
- no sound

have no idea what to do. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you entered recovery mode. Press esc at boot to get grub booting options and make sure you choose the right entry